# Derived column mapping fails

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, derived-column

I am mapping data between my oracle table to the Azure SQL DB table. I need to map the name field from the Source which is like below

| Name |
| --- |
| AX1 BD |
| A1 12 |
| BC W1 |

In to source, I need to just map the characters that are before the space like

| Dest_Name |
| --- |
| AX1 |
| A1 |
| BC |

So in the SSIS, I tried to add a derived column between the source and destination

[image]

Where in the derived column I am doing like below

[image]

And the expression is like

```
SUBSTRING(NAME,1,FINDSTRING(NAME," ",1) - 1)
```

But when I am trying to execute the task, I am getting the following error on the Derived Column

> Information: 0x4004300C at DF - ORA Room Movement, SSIS.Pipeline:
> Execute phase is beginning.
>
> Error: 0xC0049067 at DF - ORA Room Movement, Derived Column [133]: An
> error occurred while evaluating the function
>
> Error: 0xC0209029 at DF - ORA Room Movement, Derived Column [133]:
> SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Derived
> Column" failed because error code 0xC0049067 occurred, and the error
> row disposition on "Derived Column.Outputs[Derived Column
> Output].Columns[Trimmed_Name]" specifies failure on error. An error
> occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There
> may be error messages posted before this with more information about
> the failure
>
> Error: 0xC0047022 at DF - ORA Room Movement, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error
> Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component
> "Derived Column" (133) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while
> processing input "Derived Column Input" (134). The identified
> component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is
> specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the
> Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted
> before this with more information about the failure.

I am not sure what I am missing here any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps one of the source columns doesn't contain a space, so `findstring()` and/or `substring()` fail?

Comment: *"There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure."* We really need those errors.

Comment: @There is nothing much, I posted all that is relevent to the error message

Comment: @BillJetzer How can I handle if the field doesnt have the space?

Answer (score 1):

I added a new field on the Oracle Source Query `Substr (NAME,1,instr(NAME,' ') - 1)` and mapped that to the destination instead of the Derived column